# datadog submit metric without measure

Tags: python, datadog

I want to submit value to datadog to generate custom metric, but I don't want to send any measure yet.

I want to run a query on my values to generate a metric.
For example I want to submit data that contains (username, product_purchased) both are string values (using python api)
and in datadog I want to query this data as :

```
select product_purchased , count(username) from data
```

to generate my own metric, is this possible in datadog.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no number, that is not a metric. There needs to be a numeric value to submit something as a metric. Datadog is not a transactional database.

What's more common is for people to send log for every transaction, and make queries based off those application logs, or to add custom span tags to their APM traces from the checkout service.

Either of those methods would allow to make queries to count the unique number of users grouped by product.

[image]